# Firefox web-extension api captureVisibleTab refturns undefined

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have been trying to create a Firefox add-on using the web extensions API. My add-on should take a screenshot of the current page the user is browsing using chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab but it returns undefined. They say that its already implemented in the API on http://arewewebextensionsyet.com/ but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function(data) {
    console.log("screenshotData: " + data); 
});
```

I have also tried passing in a window.id as the first parameter even though in the docs it says its optional, but this also returns an undefined value for data.

Does anyone have any experience with this in particular?

Comment: have you looked at the compatibility table? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/captureVisibleTab#Browser_compatibility

Comment: yea, I've been testing on Firefox nightly 49.0a1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me in Nightly 49.0a1 (2016-06-04).

Make sure you have the following permission in your manifest.json file:

```
"permissions": [ "<all_urls>" ]
```